# Pulley Systems connected with spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I am getting this problem. There is no proof in the books that i have. Here is the problem. Suppose we have a pulley as given in the image.If we stretch the mass m by x then the pulley moves by x/2. Why is that so. Where does the extra rope come from?[image]

Answer (score 1):

the rope is fixed at one end?
 so it is easier to see what happens, when you pull down the roll the distance x, than the rope at left and right are x longer, but the left end is fixed, so the mass moves 2x.